# Latex figure 2 side

Tags: graphics, positioning

I am trying to get what's on the picture:

[image]

This is what I've tried so far:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{100k_rmse_gamma.png}
    \caption{A subfigure}
    \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{1m_rmse_gamma.png}
    \caption{A subfigure}
    \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{1M}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{image1}
\captionof{figure}{A figure}
\label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{image1}
\captionof{figure}{Another figure}
\label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Do we always have to use this approach or there is a special package for addressing this?

Comment: You are most likely using `subcaption` already in your first example. That would be a special package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.47\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{The A\label{A}}\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.47\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{The B\label{B}}\end{subfigure}\\
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.47\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{The C\label{C}}\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.47\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{The Image\label{Image}}\end{subfigure}
\caption{Four subfigures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```